# jsonb + string Concatenation

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table in postgresql as follows.

```
create table user_address (
    user_address jsonb
);

insert into user_address values ( ' {
"emails":["Jagan@xxx.com","Jagan@yyy.com"]
}')

select user_address->>'emails' from user_address
```

returns just the email address.

However, I want to convert the result into comma separated string.

I could'nt use string_agg as the data is already present in text format.

Any help tp get it as comma separated value is appreciated.

Comment: Umm, it does return a string : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9c0130bf84690b1fbe11865ea8cffc16  Could you show the expected output you would prefer?

Comment: `user_address->'emails'` will return a "comma separated" string - you just need to remove the square brackets (e.g. using `translate()`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name translate works! I was just thinking whether there were any alternate ways in which we can get a comma separated value from the DB columns.  If this is the way, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for your response. I have used Translate as suggested by